# pgbouncer and postgresql configuration

Tags: postgresql

I have postgresql 9.5 on ubuntu server with 64 core and 256 GB RAMs
and the configuration in pgbouncer and postgresql.conf as below

pgbouncer.ini:

```
pool_mode = transaction
max_client_conn = 25000
autodb_idle_timeout = 3600
default_pool_size = 64
max_db_connections = 250
max_user_connections = 250
```

postgresql.conf:

```
max_connections = 2000
shared_buffers = 64GB
effective_cache_size = 192GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 335544kB
min_wal_size = 2GB
max_wal_size = 8GB
max_worker_processes = 64
```

and I have 4 web servers connected to this database server and usually concurrent users average is 2000 so what is the best practice for my case or which parameters can I change because I facing bad performance issue and when I change the connection string from the web application to be direct on the postgresql database it gonna be better ?

Comment: You are not clear concerning the "bad performance issue". 64 connections in the pool seems a lot when you do transaction pooling, but that depends on how many cores you have. `max_connections = 2000` is insane, and many other parameters are too high as well.

Comment: the bad performance happens on the web application servers that's what I meant and sorry for not clarify it well. so what is your opinion if I changes the values to be max_connections = 200, checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7, min_wal_size = 1GB,
max_wal_size = 4GB and as I mentioned in the post that my cores are 64 so what is your recommendations ?

Comment: That requires deeper analysis and performance tests. I cannot throw numbers around. I was only complaining about the parameters that have to do with the number of connections.